# Making a select dropdown open and display dropdown options using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to open a dropdown list (the same behavior you get by clicking on it). Tried .click() and it doesn't work.

Here's the code

```
$('.list-title').droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui){
    console.log('dropped!');
    console.log(event);
    console.log(ui);
    $('.select-list1').click();

  }
});
```

Here's the project I'm working on https://codepen.io/TylerL-uxai/pen/ZJqwXR

Comment: Extra details: I'm trying to drop the list item on the list title, open the <select>, and then move the list item to the selected list.

Comment: Also tried $('.select-list1').trigger('click'); and it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to force a native dropdown element to open. You'll need to use an emulation in HTML, like the Select2 plugin does.